# Remover Duplicidade de Array multidimensional javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não sei como fazer para não incluir duplicados, ou remover duplicados depois de adicionado, podem me ajudar por favor?

obs: verifiquei outros códigos que encontrei no stakoverflow e em outros sites, porém não funcionaram para mim.

```
agendaOff.length = 2

agendaOff[0][0] = 1
agendaOff[0][1] = "17/04/2018 20:25:40"

agendaOff[1][0] = 1
agendaOff[1][1] = "17/04/2018 20:25:40"

// Método que utilizo para adicionar itens no array:
$.getJSON('json/json_query_requisicao.asp',function(data){
    if(data.length > 0){ v1='';v2='';v3='';var opt ='';
        $.each(data,function(w,itens){
            v1 = data[w].id_tiporequisicao;
            v2 = data[w].datahora;
            agendaOff.push([v1,v2]);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe uma maneira extremamente prática para comparar objetos/arrays. Se você quisesse um array com valores únicos de números, strings, ou outra primitiva, bastaria utilizar `new Set(agendaOff)`. Mas como *agendaOff* possui arrays, você tem que usar uma função para comparar esses array.

Um método popularmente utilizado, é utilizar `filter` + `indexOf` para procurar por um item, e comparar sua posição com a encontrada. Se a posição do item for diferente da que o foi encontra, significa que outro item com o mesmo valor, logo é uma duplicata.

```
$.getJSON('json/json_query_requisicao.asp', function(data) {
    agendaOff = agendaOff
        .concat(data.map((item) => [item.id_tiporequisicao, item.datahora]))
        .filter((item, i, self) => self.findIndex((itemF) => item[0] === itemF[0] && item[1] === itemF[1]) === i);
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Obrigado, eu tinha construído algo parecido mais sem o filter, vlw obrigado.